# q console has so many bracket, gradually grow from one to many

Tags: console, display, kdb

I am using windows 10 and kdb 3.6, at first, the q console has only one bracket, but as I practice on it, gradually it grows many duplicated ones. It works fine but looks annoying. How can I get rid of those?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing the additional brackets due to errors that occur inside functions/lambdas. When an error occurs you are entered into the q debugger. To remove the brackets and exit the debugger type `\` in your terminal and hit enter.

You can read more about the [q debugger here](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/debug/#debugger).

Answer (score 1):

Thomas has already explained how you're entering the debugger due to errors occurring inside of functions, and that entering `\` will exit the current 'layer' you're in. I just wanted to add that if you enter `\` while not in the debugger (i.e. your current prompt is `q)`), then your prompt will become  (two blank spaces), and the interpreter will begin evaluating k instead of q. While in the k interpreter, you can enter `\` to switch back to the q interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the supplementary, I've encountered this situation, glad to know the reason behind the scene